# Read/Write string array in memcache or memory

Tags: google-app-engine

I need to add to a string array (in possibly memcache or memory, but not the datastore) a number of times per minute. (and bearing in mind that there are a few JVM instances).

Then once a minute, a cron job comes along and fetches the array contents and once finished with it, it clears the array.

But the trouble is that (a) using memory there is an instance of the array per jvm instance so it doesn't work. And (b) How can I avoid overwriting data or causing synchronisation issues doing something like this with memcache? What is the alternative (without using the datastore)

The array will only ever be about 100 max entries.

Comment: memcache comes with sync tools built in (e.g. compare and set).

Comment: The problem with using memcache for this is that it is by design, *not* reliable. If you store this string array in memcache it could be disappear at any time. This is probably not what you want.

Using the design you outline, you could store the array in a durable datastore or database, though of course it would be slower than just dealing with memory.